# How to use dotenv with a specific file name in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, dotenv

I have multiple env files in root of my project, myApp.env and myApp-test.env.

I saw the code to load dotenv and wrote as below :

```
Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.configure()
                                    .directory(".")
                                    .ignoreIfMalformed()
                                    .ignoreIfMissing()
                                    .load();
```

**Where should I mention the name of file (myApp-test.env) which need to be loaded by dotenv. I do not find option to mention the name of file.**

Since this is a spring boot project , my env files are present in same directory where pom.xml is present. **Can I assume that "." will pick the file from that location?**

Comment: Why are you using Dotenv instead of the built-in functionality Spring Boot already supplies?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- In order to solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228109/better-way-to-set-testcontainer-properties-from-default-applicaton-yml-in-spring  where I want get properties for test container out of spring context

Comment: Ah. I have a solution to that particular puzzle around here somewhere, but not handy at the moment. Have you considered Testcontainers?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I am using testcontainers only. Problem is that I am providing hardcoded values and my requirement is that it should read those values from application.yml. Since I am starting the testcontainers using BeforeEachCallback, at that time spring context is unavailable , so i can't get any of application.yml properties